# Openpyxl deleting cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i want to pick the last `20` items of a list copy them a new spreadsheet, and once copied i want to `delete` them from the first spreadsheet.

i have the first part going (copy the last 20) but im not sure how to `delete` that cell so it doesnt appear as `none` after i save it.

filtered = [-20:]
how do i delete those 20 cells from the spreadsheet?

```
def cell_values(somesheet):
    # extract the last 20 items from the worksheet
    filtered = [x for x in somesheet.rows if x is not None]
    last20 = filtered[-20:]
    extracted_values = []

    for row in last20:
        for cell in row:
            # print cell.value
            extracted_values.append(cell.value)
```

the problem is that `filtered = [x for x in sheet.rows if x is not None]` is not working and actually appending `None` items to the `filtered` list

how can i make sure that its only picking the last 20 items that are not `none`?
as well as delete them once i have picked them from the list

Comment: i tried using garbage_collect() on the worksheet, but got an error that says `this method is private and should not be called directly`

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can delete cells see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27280801/429982).  Also, I'd guess your cells aren't really `None`, but perhaps the string: 'none' instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[x for x in somesheet.rows if x is not None]` will return a list of rows because `ws.rows` returns a list of rows.

There is currently no way to remove cells from a worksheet. The best thing is to set their values to None. Unless they have special formatting they will be removed from the worksheet when the file is saved. Calling `ws.garbage_collect()` is deprecated because it makes no sense.