# Openpyxl deleting cells / clearing content

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I was looking for a way of deleting or clearing some cells content. After searching, it seems it is not a straightforward thing to do with openpyxl. Found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931176/openpyxl-deleting-cells) where is advised to set the cells to None. I did that, but when I try to append data, it still appends it to end of all the rows I set to None.

```
def clear_sheet(this_sheet):
    '''
    Clear all cells starting from third row. we keep our header and
    replaces other rows content by None
    '''
    dst_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(dest_filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
    dst_ws=dst_wb.get_sheet_by_name(this_sheet)
    #We kee the header located in row 2, and set the rest to None
    if dst_ws.cell('A3').value is not None: #check if already cleared content
        for row in dst_ws.iter_rows(row_offset=2):
            for cell in row:
                cell.value=None
    dst_wb.save(dest_filename)



def copy_data(searchMilestone):
    '''
    gets data from the sequence file
    '''
    dst_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(dest_filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
    dst_ws=dst_wb.get_sheet_by_name(sequence_sheet)
    data =[]
    print dst_ws.max_row #here should return 3, but it seems it is counting all the cells we set to None
    for i in xrange(sequenceWs.nrows):
        #this reading part is done using xlrd module
        milestone=sequenceWs.cell(i,1).value
        execution=sequenceWs.cell(i,2).value
        system=sequenceWs.cell(i,16).value
        if searchMilestone in milestone and 'WC' in execution:
            #copy some data
            line=[data, data, data]
            dst_ws.append(line)
    dst_wb.save(dest_filename)
```

In the workbook where I write data to, I have freeze panes and some filters (showing all data). Any suggestion on how to force append from row3 after clearing content? I am using python 2.7 and openpyxl 2.3.

Comment: I am unsure what the differences are, but using openpyxl 2.4 seems to work. I change the value of cells I want to clear content and after closing the file, they are treated as empty cells.