# Delete Cell in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

openpyxl offers the ability to delete a column or a row.

```
ws.delete_cols(index)
ws.delte_row(index)
```

Is there a possible way to delete a specific cell?

```
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                 print(cell.coordinate)
```

There i want to delete the specific cell.

The Problem is, the two functions are integers and the cell is a string "A1" for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openpyxl deleting cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931176/openpyxl-deleting-cells)

Comment: No this does not answear my question...

Comment: Well, it should. Try this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259478/delete-cells-in-excel-using-python-2-7-and-openpyxl/27280801#27280801
Both are answered by the maintainer of openpyxl, and state very clearly that you cannot delete cells in openpyxl. The second details why.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete an individual cell.

But you can remove the contents by setting its value to None:

```
cell.value=None
```

Comment: Remember though that this would only remove the contents. Style and formatting would remain.

Comment: is it possible to delete the formula?

Comment: @Mark Baumann; yes, if you are setting the value of the cell to None then you are deleting the contents of the cell whether it be a value or a formula.

Comment: As a value a formula is a string. To create an empty formula you can set the value to an empty string, but I guess in this context the difference with None is minimal. If you don't succeed in doing that your cell might be protected. To remove the protection you often need a password, so you would have to turn to the creator of the excel sheet and negotiate.

Comment: I get an error merge cell. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I guess that is a new question.